# I can't unlock a swimlane in draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I have an existing swim lane diagram with flows and connectors. I want to move the 3 rightmost lanes over to the right but the 4th rightmost lane keeps hiding behind the lanes I move. It seems locked - there is no Collapse square in the left corner of the title header as in the other lanes. Is it somehow locked?

Answer (score 1):

In order to change lane order, select the one you'd like to move and click keyboard arrows left/right or right-click its title and select "To Back" or "To Front".
When lines are added, they should have collapse icon so I am not sure how you added them. Try with right-click the last swimlane's title and select "Duplicate" in order to add new lanes. When you finish, reorder them ass suggested.